# Connector is not giving a straight line in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

Please, the connector "the tools that join two objects together" in my AnyLogic is not giving a straight line anymore.

Please, how can I solve this?

Please check the attached screenshot. Unlike every other connection[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SbIW.png) in this flowchart, the connection between batch and sink is not straight[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dh8LT.png).

Please, help

Comment: There are different types of connectors, best share a screen to explain what you mean. See here for more tips how to ask good questions here: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

If you mean something like this:

[image]

Just double-click on the handle you don't like and it goes away. And here is the [help](https://anylogic.help/advanced/libraries/connector.html) on this and more.